# Select Box Navigation: widow opening on page load rather than change

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, dom-events

I've got a select box with some options.  I want to allow a user to choose an option and then be taken to a URL stored in that option's value attribute.  However, my script keeps opening the new window on page load, not on change.  Why?!  Help!

```
function selectBoxNav() {
"use strict";
var mySelectBox = document.getElementById('mySelectBox');
var myOption = mySelectBox.options[mySelectBox.selectedIndex];
var myURL = myOption.value;
function newWindow() {
  window.open(myURL);
}
mySelectBox.addEventListener('change', newWindow(), false);
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', selectBoxNav(), false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the function to `addEventListener()`, but instead you're calling it and passing its return value. `newWindow()` calls the function. To pass it you should remove the parentheses: `mySelectBox.addEventListener('change', newWindow, false);`