# how to create instances of a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to add an event listener to a object for example:

```
this.startLoading = function(){
     this.a.addEventListener("complete", this.loadingHandler()); this gives me an error
},

this.loadingHandler = function(){
    console.log("im doing something")
}
```

> ERROR:  *"Uncaught Error: addListener only takes instances of
>   Function. The listener for event "complete" is "undefined"*

However if I put the loadingHandler() function inside the scope it works, for example:

```
this.startLoading = function(){
     var loadingHandler = function(){...}
     this.a.addEventListener("complete", loadingHandler()); // this works
 },
```

Im not sure what instances of a function means in that regard?

Comment: If `loadingHandler` is exactly the same as `this.loadingHandler`, I thought both wouldn't work...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select Box Navigation: widow opening on page load rather than change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548153/select-box-navigation-widow-opening-on-page-load-rather-than-change)

Comment: Yes there are a zillion duplicates of this question. However, the nature of the issue is subtle, and the basic similarities between the questions are often not clear to JavaScript newcomers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put `()` after a reference to a function, that means to **call** the function, and the value of the expression is whatever the function returns.

Your second example, that you say works, actually will not work, and you'll get the same error if the "startLoading" function is called.

Because you probably need to retain the proper context (`this`), what you probably need is

```
this.a.addEventListener("complete", this.loadingHandler.bind(this));
```

The `.bind()` method returns a function (exactly what `addEventListener` requires) that in turn will invoke your function such that `this` has the value requested.

Comment: Thank you! now i understand what bind does. Wow